# Directus 7 App for a community contributed site

Tags: directus

Directus 7 is a headless cms which also has an App for editing data. I want to create a website where the public will be able to publish data.

So should I define users in the directus_users table and give them access to the Directus Application so they can contribute and edit data they have created, or should I define users in my own tables and write a frontend for them to create and edit data, and leave the Directus Application for administrators?

I'm asking because I am new to Directus 7 and don't yet have a good grasp of the intentions of the Directus 7 Application.

Answer (score 1):

Developer of Directus here.

There is no given way to do things, it depends on what you want to achieve with your application.

If all you're looking for is posting new public data, without having users in your app, you can open up creation of new items in a certain collection for the **public role**.

If you need users that have specific push access to certain collections, you can do either one of two things:

1. **Use a role in Directus**
   This allows you to manage their access very granular in the system, but it also means that your user has access to the (specified) data through the Directus app. This might not be an issue for you, but it's a good thing to keep in mind.
2. **Create a new Application Users collection which holds the users of your app, unrelated from Directus**.
   This means that by default, there's no access to Directus whatsoever, which means you will have to implement your own auth system and add the rows to the database in your own server side.